# При редактировании в другую таблицу ячейка не вставляется

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14xCQeYRydiBRNnCi_QZ9WSQeUmsRN1Zhvj1_hgqeARg");
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("polychilos");
}
```

При редактировании в другую таблицу ячейка не вставляется, однако при тестировании скрипта всё нормально вставляется.

Не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автоматически запускаемая функция onEdit, так называемый простой триггер, имеет доступ только к той таблице, к которой скрипт привязан. Она не может изменять или даже читать другие таблицы. Это ограничение описано [здесь](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) и мотивировано соображениями безопасности.

При ручном запуске функция имеет те же права доступа, что и пользователь, запустивший её.

Нужно заменить простой триггер на [устанавливаемый](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Процесс создания описан [здесь](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). Функция, запущенная устанавливаемым триггером, имеет те же права доступа, что и пользователь, создавший этот триггер.